# Refreshing makers (ClusterItems) in Google Maps v2 for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, markerclusterer

I'm using [Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/) and I'm downloading certain images from internet that I want to use as markers.
The way I'm doing it is like in the following snippet:

```
class MarkerItemClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MarkerItem> {
...
    @Override
        protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MarkerItem item,
                final MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
            super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
            mImageLoader.get(item.getImageUrl(), new ImageListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.i("XXX", error.toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    if (response != null && response.getBitmap() != null) {
                        mImageIcon.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                        Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
                        Bitmap bhalfsize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 150,
                                150, false);
                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .fromBitmap(bhalfsize));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

The problem is, that when the image is downloaded, the map (and thus the marker) doesn't refresh, so most of the times (but not always) I still see the red default markers.

I tried to do `mImageIcon.invalidate(); mImageIcon.requestLayout();` but there's still no luck.

Is there anyway to achieve this?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to make all this stuff in

```
protected void onClusterItemRendered(T clusterItem, Marker marker) {
    ...
}
```

In `onBeforeClusterItemRendered` you set icon on `MarkerOptions` in async callback. At this time it could be added to map and become real `Marker`. So you icon will be set to already useless object.

That's why you need to do it in `onClusterItemRendered`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have GoogleMap object declared as:
        private GoogleMap mMap;

In onResponse() method before applying any change to marker, try writing following statement to clear previous markers:
        mMap.clear();

Now set your new marker.

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late but i write it down so it can be useful for somebody looking for a solution like i was.
Basically what you have to do is refresh the marker and not the `ClusterItem`, but i used my own `ClusterItem` implementation to store some important data. 
So your code inside `onBeforeClusterItemRendered` becomes like this:

```
LatLngBounds bounds = map.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds; //take visible region on map
if(bounds.contains(item.getPosition()) && !item.hasImage()) { //if item is not inside that region or it has an image already don't load his image
    mImageLoader.get(item.getImageUrl(), new ImageListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("XXX", error.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                if (response != null && response.getBitmap() != null) {
                    mImageIcon.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                    Bitmap icon = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();
                    Bitmap bhalfsize = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(icon, 150,
                            150, false);

                    //Set has image flag
                    item.setHasImage(true);

                    //Find the right marker
                    MarkerManager.Collection markerCollection = mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection();
                    Collection<Marker> markers = markerCollection.getMarkers();
                    for (Marker m : markers) {
                        if (id.equals(m.getTitle())) {
                            //set the icon
                            m.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(image));
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    });
}
```

And your `MyItem` class must have some parameters which are useful for remember our stuff:

```
public class MyItem implements ClusterItem {

private String itemId;
private LatLng mPosition;
private WMWall wall;
private boolean hasImage = false;

public MyItem(double latitude, double longitude) {
    mPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
}

@Override
public LatLng getPosition() {
    return mPosition;
}

public WMWall getWall() {
    return wall;
}

public void setWall(WMWall wall) {
    this.wall = wall;
}

public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
}

public void setItemId(String itemId) {
    this.itemId = itemId;
}

public boolean hasImage() {
    return hasImage;
}

public void setHasImage(boolean hasImage) {
    this.hasImage = hasImage;
}
}
```

It is really important to load only the images of markers contained into bounds, otherwise you'll run into OOM.
And if the `hasImage()` method returns true we don't need to load the image again since it is already stored into the marker object.