# Redraw only being called on ClusterItems that have received position updates

Tags: android, google-maps

It appears that Google Maps API does some magic in the background that prevents `ClusterItem`s from being updated unless they've received positional updates.

Unfortunately, that means if I want to change my markers' appearance at different zoom levels, the appearance won't be refreshed until the markers receive new position data.

Is there any way to get around this?

I'm currently doing my map refresh this way:

```
HashSet<customClusterItem> limitedDisplaySet = new HashSet<>();
mClusterManager.clearItems();

//...build limitedDisplaySet

mClusterManager.addItems(limitedDisplaySet);
mClusterManager.cluster();
```

Comment: This issue can be resolved by using onBeforeClusterItemRendered method.
Please Refer to [Refreshing makers (ClusterItems) in Google Maps v2 for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22610517/refreshing-makers-clusteritems-in-google-maps-v2-for-android) and [MarkerOptions](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/issues/42).

Comment: @adjuremods I already have that implemented in my `CustomClusterRenderer`. Unfortunately, markers are only redrawn if they haven't been drawn before. Otherwise, they are simply animated to a new position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this problem by creating a copy constructor for my `ClusterItem` and copying my list of `ClusterItem`s when I need to perform a redraw on them outside of the de-clustering event.

The reason this works is because the default `ClusterRenderer` keeps a cache of all the markers it has already drawn. When we make a copy of a `ClusterItem`, it is considered a new object in the `ClusterRenderer`'s cache, which means the renderer needs to draw a new `Marker` to represent the object. This emulates a "redraw" of the original `Marker`.