# Show and update icon of marker in java android google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I use the code from github(It's not my code) as an example
https://github.com/mitchtabian/Google-Maps-2018/tree/displaying-trip-duration-of-polylines-end

This is my issue:

- Let's assume that there are some users (markers).
- I want to change the icon of marker to another picture from the internet, but it doesn't work.

I have two problems:

1. The `onBeforeClusterItemRendered()` method doesn't show the image.
   If I use the image from the resource as in the original example then it works.
2. The `setUpdateMarker()` method changes two images only on one marker instead of showing the image on each marker.

   ```
   @Override protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(ClusterMarker item, 
   MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
       super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
       Bitmap mIcon = null ;
       try {
           InputStream in = new URL(item.getIconPath()).openStream();
           mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
           imageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon);
           Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon();
           markerOptions.icon(
              BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)).title(item.getTitle());
       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } 
   } 

   public void setUpdateMarker(ClusterMarker clusterMarker) {
       marker = getMarker(clusterMarker);
       if (marker != null) {
           marker.setPosition(clusterMarker.getPosition());
           new DownloadImageTask().execute(clusterMarker.getIconPath());
       } 
   }

   private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

       @Override
       protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
           Bitmap mIcon = null;
           try {
               InputStream in = new URL(urls[0]).openStream();
               mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return mIcon;
       }

       @Override
       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
           if (marker!=null && result != null) {
               Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(result, 
                   markerWidth, 
                   markerHeight,
                   false);
               marker.setIcon(
                   BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizedBitmap));
           }
       } 
   }
   ```

Updated: I show the constructor of this class too:

```
public class MyClusterManagerRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<ClusterMarker> {
    private static final String TAG = " ClusterManagerRenderer";
    private final IconGenerator iconGenerator;
    private final ImageView imageView;
    private final int markerWidth;
    private final int markerHeight;
    private final int padding;
    private Marker marker;


    public MyClusterManagerRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap googleMap,
                                    ClusterManager<ClusterMarker> clusterManager) {

        super(context, googleMap, clusterManager);

        // initialize cluster item icon generator
        iconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context.getApplicationContext());
        imageView = new ImageView(context.getApplicationContext());
        markerWidth = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_marker_image);
        markerHeight = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_marker_image);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(markerWidth, markerHeight));
        padding = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.custom_marker_padding);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        iconGenerator.setContentView(imageView);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your method in onClusterItemRendered() method. Take a look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34029984/7917629

```
@Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(ClusterMarker item, final Marker marker) {
        String imageUrl = item.getImageUri();

        // here you can call your background task
        // or some other option like Glide
        // you put your icon as: 
        // marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(resizedBitmap));
    }
```

------ **Update how to use glide** (my version 4.7.1) here

```
   @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(EventMarker clusterItem, final Marker marker) {
        String imageUrl = clusterItem.getImageUri();

        if (imageView != null && imageUrl != null && !imageUrl.isEmpty()) {
            Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
                    .load(imageUrl)
                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                            .optionalCircleCrop()
                            .placeholder(R.mipmap.default_event_cover_rounded)
                            .error(R.mipmap.default_event_cover_rounded)
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                    .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                            imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
                            Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon();
                            try {
                                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.d("TAG", "onResourceReady: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

This how you can update your icon after:
Define some `Map<String, Marker> markers` in top of your CustomClusterRender, initialize it in constructor. add your marker with some key after you this `marker.setIcon`. Add like `markers.put(clusterItem.getId(), marker);` your custom cluster must have unique id. your method will be

```
public void updateMarker(final String id, String imgUrl) {
        if (markers.size() > 0) {
            if (iconImage != null) {
                Glide.with(mContext.getApplicationContext())
                        .load(imgUrl)
                        .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                .optionalCircleCrop()
                                .placeholder(R.mipmap.default_event_cover_rounded)
                                .error(R.mipmap.default_event_cover_rounded)
                                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL))
                        .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                                iconImage.setImageDrawable(resource);
                                Bitmap icon = iconGenerator.makeIcon();
                                try {
                                    markers.get(id).setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon));
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.d("TAG_SNAP", "onResourceReady: " + e.getMessage() + markers.get(id).getTitle());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Alex what exactly not help when you use it in onClusterItemRendered? are you sure that you get result from the internet? Did you tried glide or picasso?

Comment: I wrote the same code that you see in the onBeforeClusterItemRendered @Vadim Eksler

Comment: The method onBeforeClusterItemRendered will ends before your internet request will ends

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will try again. Do you know how to solve the second issue ?@Vadim Eksler

Comment: About setUpdateMarker() ? I dont see were you call it.

Comment: I suggest you to try to use glide or picasso for this, it very easy

Comment: I call from UserListFragment.java in github @Vadim Eksler

Comment: Can you give me an example of code how to use onClusterItemRendered with Glide ? @Vadim Eksler

Comment: What is SimpleTarget ? I show my constructor too. @Vadim Eksler

Comment: we have same code in constructor so I update it one more time, take a look. SimpleTarget  class from `import com.bumptech.glide.request.target.SimpleTarget;`

Comment: Thanks, it works but the icons appear after a few seconds and not immediately. Another question: if I want to change icon while running the app. How I need to do it ? That what I want to do in  setUpdateMarker @Vadim Eksler

Comment: 1. you can except answer if it helps. 2. "few seconds" because internet request takes time. 3. You can save map of ids (key) and marker (value) in method `onClusterItemRendered` and make new glide request in method `setUpdateMarker(id, imgUrl)` find by id in your map and use it.

Comment: Could you give me an example ? @ Vadim Eksler

Comment: @Alex added example

Comment: 1 .Do you know why the getMarker doesn't work as excepted ?  In other words, Why can't I use with getMarker instead of creating Map ?@ Vadim Eksler

Comment: 2. The onClusterItemRendered runs after that markers were added on GoogleMaps. So, Why will it works ? After change path of icon while running App, the icon is not changed. After rerun App, it changes @ Vadim Eksler

Comment: 2. When you call the function `updateMarker()` you call it from same instance? you create in activity/fragment global variable `MyClusterManagerRenderer` and use on it? or you make new clusterManager?

Comment: 1.  `getMarker()` from what object?

Comment: 1. It is member function of DefaultClusterRenderer class @Vadim Eksler

Comment: 2. I run it from Fragment with handler. There is something strange, When I change icon then marker is removed from my map but when I restart App then it shows. @ Vadim Eksler